# JMS Serializer Bundle - Create group at runtime

Tags: php, symfony, jmsserializerbundle

I'm trying to obtain a sort of custom API creation by allowing the user to select which fields to serialize from a web interface.

One possible solution could be to allow the user to create the equivalent of JMS Serialization groups.

Is there some way to configure a JMS Group at runtime so i can call the following ?

```
$serializer->serialize(new X(), 'json', SerializationContext::create()->setGroups(array('my_custom_group')));
```

Comment: Did you check e.g. http://jolicode.com/blog/how-to-implement-your-own-fields-inclusion-rules-with-jms-serializer ?

Comment: that was EXACTLY what i was looking for, but couldn't find any documentation. i was searching via the wrong approach.
If you put this as an answer i'll check it solved! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the

```
 interface ExclusionStrategyInterface
 {
   public function shouldSkipClass(ClassMetadata $metadata, Context $context);
   public function shouldSkipProperty(PropertyMetadata $property, Context $context);
 }
```

A very extensive example how this can be used please check this link:

http://jolicode.com/blog/how-to-implement-your-own-fields-inclusion-rules-with-jms-serializer